# Hashing by Equals instead of SameQ

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching, replacement

I have some numerical code involving complex numbers representing points on a plane. Some of these are equal but not identical, ie

> ```
> {Exp[2 Pi I (-1./10)], ..., Exp[2 Pi I (9./10)]}
> ```

I want to make (the equivalent of) a dictionary mapping each to its coordinate in the list (because using Position repeatedly would take too long). But both Downvalues and matching rules (with a Dispatch table) match based on the form of the expression rather than its value (and Hash hashes based on the form of the expression as well).
Eg, if

> {a == b, a===b}
>     ==>   {True, False}
>   then
>
> f[a] = 1; {f[a], f[b]}
>   {1, f[b]}

Is there some way to associate the points with their position (with faster than O(n) lookup) based on their value? I feel like there should also be some way to do it using rounding, but I haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: Hello Zaq.  I believe a similar question has been asked before. (I shall look for it.)  One possibility is to use `Round` (with a second parameter) to quantize your data.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: [(15907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15907).  And this is the one I think I was remembering: [(1072)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1072) -- also not an exact duplicate, but quite close.