# Problem simulating a wave on a string by solving the wave equation as a difference equation.

Tags: physics

This is a question I posted earlier however the purpose of what I'm doing is going to be expounded much more clearly.

```
yy[x_, t_] := Which[x == 0, yy[0, t] = 0, x == 1, yy[1, t] = 0, t == 0, yy[x, 0] = Exp[-1000 (x - .3)^2]]
```

This code is the boundary condition and initial condition for my wave. At x=0 the amplitude equals zero and at x=1 the amplitude is also zero for all times. For t=0 the wave is a Gaussian centered at x=.3

```
Flatten[Table[yy[x, t + 3./10000.] = yy[x + 1./100., t] + yy[x - 1./100., t], {t,  0, 3./10000., 3./10000.}, {x, 1./100., 99./100., 1./100.}], 1]
```

This runs my problem and uses the values of yy at t=0 to calculate t=3./10000. later. However when I run this program I get these nulls for the next time step of t=3./10000. This runis the calculation and I cannot get enough good data point for later times.

Help will be very much appreciated. I never had this problem before and I tried everything I know and none of it worked to fix this problem.

Comment: I provided a brief explanation of the problem and a link to a solution in comments to your other question.  Did you look at them?

Comment: I did see them. I don't see how rounding is going to help me. My numbers are less then far less then one so when I round them they just turn to zero.

Comment: Did you try `Round[t, 0.0001]` or something like that?

Comment: You mean yy[Round[x,t]]?

Comment: No, I meant to round `x` and `t` to multiples of `0.01` and `0.0001`, which seems appropriate.  That would take care of the round-off error.  But trying it out, doesn't seem to work.  There may be something about your scheme I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be overkill, but here's a version with everything rounded that gets rid of the extraneous `Null`.

```
Clear[yy];
dx = 1./100; dt = 1./10000;
yy[x0_, t0_] := With[{x = Round[x0, dx], t = Round[t0, dt]},
  Which[
   x == 0, yy[0, t] = 0,
   x == 1, yy[1, t] = 0,
   t == 0, yy[x, 0] = Exp[-1000 (x - .3)^2]]
  ]

Table[With[{
   x = Round[x, dx],
   t = Round[t, dt],
   t2 = Round[t + 3./10000., dt]},
  yy[x, t2] = yy[Round[x + 1./100., dx], t] + yy[Round[x - 1./100., dx], t]
  ],
 {t, 0, 3./10000., 3./10000.},
 {x, 1./100., 99./100., 1./100.}]
```

See [Memoization of Rounded inputs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/memoization-of-rounded-inputs) for related strategies.

---

**Some explanation**

The extraneous values of `Null` come from `Which`, not because `Which` is misused by not having a default case, but because of pattern-matching problems in the memoization of `yy`.  (The OP seems to have noticed something like this in [How to stop Mathematica from turning .02 into 0.019999999999999997`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79130/how-to-stop-mathematica-from-turning-02-into-0-019999999999999997), although it is not remarked upon explicitly in the question.)

The underlying cause is round-off error.  Note, for instance, that `0.01 + 0.01` equals `` 0.02` ``, while `0.03 - 0.01` equals `` 0.019999999999999997` ``. This is due to numerical round-off error consistent with IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point numbers. Note that `0.02 - (0.03 - 0.01)` equals `2^(-58)`, a one-bit loss of precision.

The problem with the code is subtler, though. While `` 0.019999999999999997` == 0.02` `` returns `True`, as patterns, `` 0.019999999999999997` `` does not match `` 0.02` ``.  The problem arises specifically in the snippet of the OP's code,

```
yy[x - 1./100., t]
```

when `x = 0.03`.  For `t = 3./10000`, the value has been memoized as `` yy[0.02`, 0.0003`] ``; but code snippet evaluates first as `` yy[0.019999999999999997`, 0.0003`] ``, which in turn evaluates to `Null` because it does not match `` yy[0.02`, 0.0003`] `` and it falls through the `Which` cases.  The rounding in the solution I gave, some of which is not strictly necessary, makes the arguments in the memoized definitions and evaluations of `yy` match each other when they are meant to be equal.

Comment: It works thank you so much I can't express how happy I am. I'll study your code intensively so that this problem does not happen again.

Comment: @DanielBerkowitz You're welcome.

Comment: Personally, I feel this Q&A should be merged with the OP's other one, [79130](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79130/how-to-stop-mathematica-from-turning-02-into-0-019999999999999997).

Comment: @DanielBerkowitz FWIW, the same computation can be achieved with ``nsteps = 2; NestList[Join[{0.}, ListConvolve[{1, 0, 1}, #], {0.}] &, Developer`ToPackedArray@Table[N@yy[x, 0.], {x, 0., 1., 1./100.}], nsteps]`` - It's about ten times faster or more.